# attempt to index global 'ent' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, null, garrys-mod

Before I start I should say that I'm fairly new to programming. Currently trying to make a script that spawns the player at the same spot where he died, however whenever I run the script it gives me this error.

> [ERROR] addons/aaa/lua/weapons/test.lua:9: attempt to index global
>   'ent' (a nil value)

Here is the code.

```
--Command
concommand.Add( "test_command", function( ply )
  local hi = ply:GetPos()
  ply:Spawn()
  ent.ply:setPos (hi)
  end)
```

(That's the entire script btw) If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It means that `ent` is undefined at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to set position to the `ply` variable.

```
concommand.Add( "test_command", function( ply )
  local hi = ply:GetPos()
  ply:Spawn()
  ply:SetPos(hi)
  end
)
```

From the docs, it should be `SetPos` and not `setPos`.

Comment: That worked thanks, I didn't realize capitalization mattered that much. o.0